# optimize java method (finding all ways to reach a point on basis of dice)

Tags: java, optimization, tail-recursion

i made this method to solve problem in which i need to cover a distance by taking a step from (1-6) as per dice and compute all possible ways to reach distance
i made this method

```
static int watchCount(int distance)
{
    // Base cases
    if (distance<0) return 0;
    if (distance==0) return 1;

    return watchCount(distance-1) +
        watchCount(distance-2) +
        watchCount(distance-3)+
        watchCount(distance-4) +
        watchCount(distance-5)+
        watchCount(distance-6);

}
```

but for large values like >500 this method is taking very long any help to optimize would be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: what are you looking for?

Comment: use loops. while or for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a cache like this (the same idea to @PiotrWilkin):

```
static int watchCount(int distance, Integer[] cache) {
    // Base cases
    if (distance < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (distance == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (cache[distance-1] == null) {
        cache[distance-1] = watchCount(distance - 1, cache)
                + watchCount(distance - 2, cache)
                + watchCount(distance - 3, cache)
                + watchCount(distance - 4, cache)
                + watchCount(distance - 5, cache)
                + watchCount(distance - 6, cache);
    }
    return cache[distance-1];
}
```

EDIT iterative implementation:

```
public static int iterativeWatchCount(int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    int index = 0;
    int[] cache = new int[6];
    cache[cache.length - 1] = 1;
    int sum = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++, index = (index + 1) % cache.length) {
        sum = cache[0] + cache[1] + cache[2] + cache[3] + cache[4] + cache[5];
        cache[index] = sum;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: thanks ! on using  iterative implementation of method when i supply a value like 620 i am getting value -1702834607 how can i fix .

Comment: @PRS change int to long

Comment: i changed it to long already but in changing long i get i different value -8879611896424360376.

Comment: @PRS change long to Biginteger but this change need more efford

Comment: @Perez Cabrera `code`
         sum = cache[0].add(cache[1]).add(cache[2]).add(cache[3]).add(cache[4]).add(cache[5]);//getting null pointer error here may you please help or hint me here.

Comment: @PRS you must to initialize to zero.

Comment: @Perez : this code however not giving desired result

Comment: @PRS what is the input and output desired?

Comment: @Perez kindly ignore i fixed that error was intializing 0th element of array

Answer (score 1):

This is a classical problem for dynamic programming. Create an array of size `n` (where `n` is the number you're looking for) and work your way back, updating the array by incrementing the number of ways to obtain the value. This way, you can do it in `O(n)` complexity (currently the complexity is exponential).

Comment: For example: there is 1 way to reach 500 from 499 - by 1; the number of ways to reach 500 from 498 is 1 + the number of ways to reach 500 from 499 - and so on...